# Angular moment datepicker - how to show original date?

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, momentjs, angularjs-ng-model

I am trying to use the Angular Moment DatePicker (https://indrimuska.github.io/angular-moment-picker/) and for the most part it is working just fine. What is NOT working for me is that I can't get it to display the original ng-model date value. I only see a date show up AFTER I use the picker to choose one. The model value IS being set and I can view it as you would expect to using bracket notation {{ fl.dataValue }}

```
<input class="form-control"
       ng-model="fl.dataValue"
       moment-picker="fl.dataValue"
       format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm">
```

Any thoughts? Is this working for you?

Comment: what happens when you hard code in a value there for the date? will that date value render on page load?

Comment: one other thought: what if you add the "value" attribute to the input element?

Comment: Thank you. Neither of these seemed to do anything. It seems as if, when the control is in an input element as opposed to anything else, it wants to be a picker for a new value, as opposed to an editor.

Answer (score 0):

While not a perfect answer, this is a work-around, by using the original value as a placeholder

```
                    <input class="form-control"
                           ng-model="fl.dataValue"
                           moment-picker="fl.dataValue"
                           format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"
                           placeholder="{{fl.dataValue}}"
                           ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }">
```